# Where store gcm Token for GoogleCloudMessaging?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences, android-security

I have application where registration on gcm (for push). I take and immediately send to server.
Looks loke this:

```
try {
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String gcmKey = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.GCM_CLIENT_ID),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE,
                    null);

        Timber.i("gcm registration token: %s", gcmKey);

        sendTokenToServer(gcmKey); //method with sending data to my server

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e(e, "failed get token");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But in this moment business logic changed and i obliged send this data (String gsmKey) not immediately. I need store this data and send after a while with another data.

But i don't know how many security-sensitive data - gcm token. 
Where i need save this String value? In SharedPrefernces will be enough or i need another (more security) saving mechanism?

Comment: You can store it in SharedPrefernces it is enough for security

Comment: and small moment, this app running only NOT-ROOTED devices. In this devices another app can get this data (in theory)?

Comment: No it is not possible at all. No other app can access the shared preference of your application so don't worry about it.

Comment: You could just call `getToken()` to get the current token in your code (hopefully during a time where your app has internet connection) where you only have to send the token towards the database. That way, you'd be sure that you'll be sending the most recent value. No need to store it temporarily.

Comment: save gcm token in share preference with AES encryption for security

Comment: @AL. i think for this. But in place (where i send need data) not very convenient checking playservices and catching errors.